# doubts installing hibernate ,hsqldb plugins for eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, plugins, hsqldb

I am taking my first steps developing web apps using Eclipse, Java EE, Hibernate, spring and hsqldb.

I installed the Helios version of Eclipse and installed WTP through the updater. But trying to install the plugins for others, I am having doubts.

Hibernate:
I tried the download jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/ as the hostname in updater and it shows 
  JBoss Tools - 3.0.3.v200910211631N-H194-GA
  JBoss Tools Integration for TPTP, BIRT - 3.0.3.v200910211631N-H194-GA

in the list.Which am I supposed to install?Where is the hibernate plugin?

hsqldb:
when I googled ,I got these links
sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb-plugin/

Is this the one?what is the update host name I am supposed to give to eclipse?

spring:
i tried springide.org/updatesite/ .It shows a list of some 10 or more items..What should I select?core /spring IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HSQLDB plugin for eclipse is an extension that can be added from within eclipse. See here for details on how to set up and use.

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hsqldb.user/4633/